# Selecting individual values from csv format in oracle pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following value in a column in Oracle db  ('abc', 'xyz')

I want to extract the values separately like abc, xyz by removing ' and (). Is there a way to do it using INSTR and SUBSTR functions?

Thanks

Comment: yes, but much more comfortable will be to use regular expressions

Comment: While simon's answer is awesome (gave +1) I'm assuming your example of `'abc', 'xyz'` is just that, an example.  In your real world data I'm assuming you will have some columns with one value and some with many values.  In which case you'd have to keep adjusting that query.  I noticed you added the `pl/sql` tag to this question.  If in fact you can use `pl/sql` then that opens up a whole slew of different approaches.

Comment: If there is any suggestion to do it in PL SQL, request you guys to please let me know.

Comment: If you just google it there are tons of examples, all pretty lengthy.  The way I do it is pretty lengthy as well.  Are you certain your data will always be formatted like your example? If so I could probably write something up real fast.  Or will some data be formatted like this... `abc,xys` (commas only)?

Comment: Yes Gordon it is like that only, the data is inside brackets and single quotes sepatared by comma select row from table; result-> ('abc','jkl','xyz')

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
with sample as (select '(''abc'', ''xyz'')' text from dual)
select substr(text,instr(text,'''',1,1) + 1,instr(text,'''',1,2) - instr(text,'''',1,1) - 1),
       substr(text,instr(text,'''',1,3) + 1,instr(text,'''',1,4) - instr(text,'''',1,3) - 1)
from sample;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but is there a way to loop if i'm not sure of how many texts it may contain. Ex: a row might have only ('abc') and other might have ('abc','jkl','xyz') and other might have ('abc','jkl')

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know what you want to do with the data once parsed.  How it could be handled in SQL vs PL/SQL to achieve your requirement could be very different.

That said, here's one way to strip surrounding parens and remove single quotes at the same time during the select using the powerful regexp_replace(source_string, pattern_string, replace_string) :

```
WITH qry AS (SELECT '(' || '''abc''' || ',' || '''xyz''' || ')' orig_string
            FROM    dual
            ) 
SELECT  regexp_replace(orig_string, '[()'']', '' ) clean_string
FROM    qry;
```

The regexp_replace pattern_string says to match a character class (defind by opening and closing square brackets) containing a left paren or a right paren or a single quote (quoted so Oracle sees it) and the replace_string replaces it with nothing.

Then, to parse the values remaining here's an example from by bag of tricks I got somewhere and tweaked for this case:

```
set serveroutput on

DECLARE
-- Build a string in the format "('abc','xyz')"
orig_string varchar2(20) := '(' || '''abc''' || ',' || '''xyz''' || ')';

CURSOR cur IS
WITH qry AS (SELECT regexp_replace(orig_string, '[()'']','' ) clean_string
             FROM    dual
            )
  SELECT    regexp_substr(clean_string, '[^,]+', 1, ROWNUM) element
  FROM    qry
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(regexp_replace (clean_string, '[^,]+')) + 1;
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN cur LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('Element:' || rec.element);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

It basically loops through the elements and prints them.  I'm sure you can adapt this to your situation.

Comment: Tried doing this WITH CTE AS (
select regexp_replace(attribute_text, '[()'']','' ) temp,user_id
       from table_a tba, table_tbb,
        where tba.role_id = tbb.role_id             
     ) SELECT regexp_substr (temp, '[^,]+', 1, rn)temp, user_id
     FROM   cte
     CROSS JOIN 
     (SELECT ROWNUM rn
          FROM  (SELECT MAX (LENGTH (regexp_replace (temp, '[^,]'))) +1  max_l from cte)
          connect by level <= max_l)
     WHERE regexp_substr (temp, '[^,]+', 1, rn) IS NOT NULL
     order by temp; but output is not coming as abc, jkl, xyz instead a space before and after jkl.

Comment: Meaning if three strings are there  ('abc,'jkl',xyz') abc and xyz get extracted as they are but the strings in between say 'jkl' in this case come with a leading and trailing space, tried using trim function but no use of it.

Comment: Used regexp_replace ( temp , '[[:space:]]', '' ) on top of the rows selected. It removed all spaces. Thank you all experts for the help.